# printing the user data in network packet

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have make a module in which i receive all incoming packets by net filter. I want to print the data (no headers) in /var/log/messages . I have tried the following printk line but its not printing the suitable message .

```
 struct sk_buff *sock_buff; 
 printk(KERN_INFO"user data :: %x",(sock_buff->data+sizeof(*sock_buff->network_header)+sizeof(*sock_buff->mac_header))  //though i want in character but i cant understand whats it printing not matching the hex of my data
  printk(KERN_INFO"user data :: %s",(sock_buff->data+sizeof(*sock_buff->network_header)+sizeof(*sock_buff->mac_header))
```

i have even used tail - sizeof(my_data); then also i am not getting desired o/p.

Comment: Use [print_hex_dump_bytes](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.3/lib/hexdump.c#L242) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your forgot take a value by pointer(*), try this

```
printk(KERN_INFO"user data :: %x",*(sock_buff->data+sizeof(*sock_buff->network_header) +sizeof(*sock_buff->mac_header));
```

As I understand, in your structure data field have a pointer type.

```
typedef struct{
  ...
  unsigned char* data;
  ...
} sk_buff;
```

Also %x specificator (number in hex) requers numerical agrument, not a pointer, that's why you should not forgot to put one small (*)

Answer (score -1):

I am no kernel hacker but looking at the skbuff.h header file it looks to me that one of `sock_buff->data` or `sock_buff->tail` is pointing to the data after the headers. In that case `printk(KERN_INFO"user data :: %s",sock_buff->data);` might do the trick.